# Addin Datarow in Datatable

Tags: vb.net

I've VB.NET function that reads data from an Excel sheet and adds rows in a Datatable.

```
Private Function LoadDataToRows(ByVal TableName As DataTable, ByVal Header As System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection) As Boolean
       Dim HeaderDataExcel As String = String.Empty    'Data Header
       For r As Integer = 1 To RangeDataArray.Rows.Count
            Dim NewRow As DataRow = TableName.NewRow
            For c As Integer = 1 To RangeDataArray.Columns.Count
                If Not (IsNothing(DirectCast(ActiveSheetToManipulate.Cells.Item(r + DataStartRow, c), Excel.Range).Value)) Then
                    Dim ValueToLoad As String = TryCast(ActiveSheetToManipulate.Cells.Item(r + DataStartRow, c), Excel.Range).Value.ToString

                    HeaderDataExcel = TryCast(ActiveSheetToManipulate.Cells.Item(DataStartRow, c), Excel.Range).Value.ToString
                    Dim indice As Integer = Header.IndexOf(HeaderDataExcel)
                    TableName.NewRow(indice) = ValueToLoad
                Else
                    'Todo
                End If
            Next
            TableName.Rows.Add(NewRow)
        Next
        Return True
    End Function
```

But no data was add to the table. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a VB.NET programmer but you probably need to change the DataTable parameter to be passed ByRef rather than ByVal

In addition is the syntax for populating the NewRow columns correct?  You should be using the created new data row instance rather than using TableName.NewRow?

I thought it was more like:

```
Dim newRow As DataRow = TableName.NewRow()

newRow ("ColumnName") = "MyNewValue"  ' Add specifying column name
newRow (2) = "AnotherValue" ' Add specifying column index

TableName.Rows.Add(newRow)
```

So your code would be something like the following (note I've changed the name of the new row variable because I think that's causing part of your confusion)

```
        Dim rowToAdd As DataRow = TableName.NewRow()
        For c As Integer = 1 To RangeDataArray.Columns.Count
            If Not (IsNothing(DirectCast(ActiveSheetToManipulate.Cells.Item(r + DataStartRow, c), Excel.Range).Value)) Then
                Dim ValueToLoad As String = TryCast(ActiveSheetToManipulate.Cells.Item(r + DataStartRow, c), Excel.Range).Value.ToString

                HeaderDataExcel = TryCast(ActiveSheetToManipulate.Cells.Item(DataStartRow, c), Excel.Range).Value.ToString
                Dim indice As Integer = Header.IndexOf(HeaderDataExcel)
                rowToAdd(indice) = ValueToLoad
            Else
                'Todo
            End If
        Next
        TableName.Rows.Add(rowToAdd)
```

Comment: I use the sintax with index.If you cabn read VB code, I define an integer named indice that's the index of the column. I can also see by debug that the var "ValueToLoad" it's correct. But no data was add to the datarow.I can see only empty rows.

Comment: Both name and index work - my point is more that you *shouldn't* be doing `**TableName**.NewRow(indice) = ValueToLoad` and instead `NewRow(indice) = ValueToLoad`.  Then if you step through the code and the row is added locally it the `ByVal/ByRef` change that is stopping it working

Comment: You don't need to pass any object ByRef if you don't create a new instance of the object in the method (eg. `TableName = new DataTable`) as Objects are ReferenceTypes.

Comment: I think that I've some problems with this line:                  TableName.NewRow(indice) = ValueToLoad                              My for cycle is repeted for n times where n is the number of the colums of the Datatable, but in debug mode I can't see the values upgrad.

Comment: @Nicholas - yes, its the pointer reference to the DataTable rather than the actual table itself.

Comment: @user1264246 - see the updated answer for how you should be populating the new row values

Comment: But TableName is a DataTable.In the point where i call the function I pass the a DataTable in a DataSet...something like this: LoadDataToRows(ds.Tables.Item("MainTable"), SheetHeader)

Comment: 1. I'm not disputing that TableName is a DataTable.  It is badly named but that's a separate issue.  2. What I'm saying is that in the creation of a new row, the population of it and then the addition of that row to the table your code is wrong and part of how you can fix that is by updating the code as I've suggested using a variable name for the new row that distinguishes it from the NewRow method of a DataTable object

Comment: "It doesn't work" how?  1. Can you see rowToAdd being populated with values 2. Does a row get added to the table 3. Or?

Comment: NO, I' can not see anithing to different. The new line is already empty.

Comment: Ok.Solved. The problem was for adding columns values to a new row I don't have to indicate the Datatable. This works NewRowToAdd(HeaderDataExcel) = ValueToLoad. Thanks a lot for your help.